# VERIFICACAO DE DUAS CAIXA DANDO ERRO

Tags: java, android-studio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
To usando essa verificação pra caso o usuario deixar a caixa de texto em branco, ele me da um alert falando que tem que inserir algo, porém não ta entrando nessa parte do codigo..

Comment: Leandro, o site tem suporte para códigos diretamente no corpo da pergunta; por favor, evite postá-los em forma de imagem.

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Comment: *"porém não ta entrando nessa parte do codigo"* que parte? se exibe o alert é pq entrou no `if` e código do `if`acaba depois disso onde fecha as chaves

Comment: @RicardoPontual então mano, mas n exibe o alert kdsksdk

Comment: então, faz um debug, pode ser a variável não seja null mas vazia, o que é diferente. Tente mudar para isso: `recebeValor.toString().trim().isEmpty())`